# Bing Image Search API returning 403: Subscription Expired

Tags: bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

Beginning this morning, our API calls to v5.0 of the bing image search API are return 403 with message "This subscription has expired." I've checked our quota, and we have plenty of requests left (we've actually used 0 for this month).

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This sounds like a question for Bing's support rather than Stack Overflow. We can't provide customer service here.

Comment: Alright - appreciate your comment. They link Stack Overflow in their website's footer, so I thought I'd try. I'll delete the question shortly. Thanks.

Comment: What website are you using to check your quota? Are you checking through the azure portal, or through datamarket?

a 403 error means you have a valid key but are either not authorized (unlikely because you would have had to set up special permissions to whitelist certain X-Search-ClientID's in the headers of queries) or you've selected the S1 tier via https://portal.azure.com and you've hit 1k queries.

Comment: You should email bingapi@microsoft.com if you want more help. They're pretty responsive.